# What TS type do I use for the `code` property when detecting a duplicate value exception in NestJS/TypeORM?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am using NestJS with TypeORM and a Postgres database.

I have set up an entity to have a unique username column, like this:

```ts
@Entity()
export class DataEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;
  
  //Other properties...
}
```

When I actually add it to my database I need to provide an error message when a duplicate username is found. The below code totally works if I force the `any` type onto `ex`, but I want to have proper TypeScript typings.  The `ex.code` property does exist on this object but I cannot locate the `.code` property on any strongly typed object!

```ts
async createThing(data: dataDto): Promise<DataEntity> {

  try {
    //Do DB operations here...
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex);
    if (ex.code === '23505') {
      //23505 is the code for a duplicate user detected in the DB
      this.logger.error(`Username '${username}' already exists!`);
      throw new ConflictException(`Username '${username}' already exists!`);
    } else {
      this.logger.error(`Failed to create data! Data: ${JSON.stringify(createOrgDto)}`);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException();
    }
  }
}
```

Ideally I think the best way to go would be  `if (ex instanceOf WhateverError && ex.code === '23505') {`, but I need to know what real TS type to use.

This is the output from the `console.log` (with some changes/redactions for specific information)

```json
QueryFailedError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UQ_e288cba8a890c81abc9dbac6b33"
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:299:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at InsertQueryBuilder.execute (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\query-builder\InsertQueryBuilder.ts:163:33)
    at SubjectExecutor.executeInsertOperations (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\persistence\SubjectExecutor.ts:434:42)
    at SubjectExecutor.execute (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\persistence\SubjectExecutor.ts:137:9)
    at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\persistence\EntityPersistExecutor.ts:182:21)
    at DataService.createData (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\data\data.service.ts:43:7) {
  query: 'INSERT INTO "Data"("id", "username", "password", "name", "logoUrl", "type", "superAdmin") VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, $2, $3, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) RETURNING "id", "logoUrl", "type", "superAdmin"',
  parameters: [
    'foo',
    '<REDACTED_PASSWORD>',
    'FooCorp'
  ],
  driverError: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UQ_e288cba8a890c81abc9dbac6b33"
      at C:\Users\chris\myproj\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:526:17
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at PostgresQueryRunner.query (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:249:25)
      at InsertQueryBuilder.execute (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\query-builder\InsertQueryBuilder.ts:163:33)
      at SubjectExecutor.executeInsertOperations (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\persistence\SubjectExecutor.ts:434:42)
      at SubjectExecutor.execute (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\persistence\SubjectExecutor.ts:137:9)
      at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\persistence\EntityPersistExecutor.ts:182:21)
      at DataService.createData (C:\Users\chris\myproj\src\data\data.service.ts:43:7) {
    length: 249,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '23505',
    detail: 'Key (username)=(foo) already exists.',
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: 'public',
    table: 'Data',
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: 'UQ_e288cba8a890c81abc9dbac6b33',
    file: 'nbtinsert.c',
    line: '666',
    routine: '_bt_check_unique'
  },
  length: 249,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '23505',
  detail: 'Key (username)=(foo) already exists.',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: 'public',
  table: 'Data',
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: 'UQ_e288cba8a890c81abc9dbac6b33',
  file: 'nbtinsert.c',
  line: '666',
  routine: '_bt_check_unique'
}
```

And yes, I have tried to use the `QueryFailedError` type, but that does not have the `code` property on it.  Will I just have to force it to an `any` type? I hope not.

Comment: The `catch` variable is _always_ either `any` or `unknown`. Presumably you have the latter, so to tell the compiler it's definitely an object with a code property you have to [narrow it](https://tsplay.dev/mpQezW).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I know that, but I need to know the specific type to narrow it to. I am hoping someone familiar with NestJS or TypeORM can give some guidance on that. I have tried looking through the package typedefs to no luck. I am starting to feel like I will just have to force cast it to `any` and ignore lint warnings